# Wrap row to the next line

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm looking for a way to wrap an `UltraGrid` row to the next line such that an horizontal scrollbar would not be needed to see the whole grid.

In HTML/CSS it would look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/zjbyE/205/

I looked for any property that could do that in the `DisplayLayout` and the `Override` sub-objects without success. Maybe I missed something obvious?

Comment: check this out maybe it will help http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~CellMultiLine.html

Comment: The link you provided explains how to make the cells' content wrap ; I want the row itself to be wrapped (checkout the `jsfiddle` link in my original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid doesn't have any way to auto-wrap the cells if that's what you are looking for. In other words, the grid won't change the position of the cells based on the available width compared to the width of the actual band.

But the grid will allow you to position cells on multiple logical rows within a data row, and in theory, you could code the Resize event of the grid to re-position the columns when they don't fit.

There are two ways to create multiple logical rows in a single data row. One is to use Column Groups and the other is to use a RowLayoutStyle.ColumnLayout. Since groups requires group headers and you didn't mention anything about those, I will use the ColumnLayout approach, which is a bit more complex, but it worked pretty well when I tried it out in a simple single-band grid.

Here's some sample code I whipped up. It's not perfect, but it works pretty well.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            this.ultraDataSource1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i });
        }

        // Hook the paint event so we can wrap the cells the first time the grid paints. 
        // We can't do it here directly, because until the grid paints, there are no UIElements
        // and the column measurements may be wrong. 
        this.ultraGrid1.Paint += UltraGrid1_Paint;

    }

    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGridLayout layout = e.Layout;
        UltraGridBand rootBand = layout.Bands[0];

        // ColumnLayout allows us to position the columns in a single data row on multiple
        // logical rows. 
        rootBand.RowLayoutStyle = RowLayoutStyle.ColumnLayout;

        // This code will be a lot more complex if we have to account for the possibility
        // that the vertical scrollbar may or may not be visible. So make it visible always
        // to spare us some headaches. 
        layout.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.Vertical;

        // This code doesn't account or multiple scroll regions to turn those off. 
        layout.MaxColScrollRegions = 1;
        layout.MaxRowScrollRegions = 1;
    }

    private void UltraGrid1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // We only need to to this the first time, so unhook the Paint event. 
        this.ultraGrid1.Paint -= UltraGrid1_Paint;

        // Wrap the grid columns. 
        UltraGrid grid = (UltraGrid)sender;
        this.WrapGridRows(grid);
    }        

    private void ultraGrid1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Wrap the grid columns. 
        UltraGrid grid = (UltraGrid)sender;
        this.WrapGridRows(grid);
    }

    private void WrapGridRows(UltraGrid grid)
    {
        UltraGridLayout layout = grid.DisplayLayout;

        // Determine the available Width of the grid.
        UIElement gridElement = layout.UIElement;
        UIElement rowColRegionIntersectionUIElement = gridElement.GetDescendant(typeof(RowColRegionIntersectionUIElement));
        int availableWidth = rowColRegionIntersectionUIElement.RectInsideBorders.Width;

        // X and y origins of each column in the ColumnLayout.
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        // Keep track of the total width that has been used up on each row. 
        int totalUsedWidth = 0;

        // Loop through the columns.
        UltraGridBand band = layout.Bands[0];
        foreach (UltraGridColumn column in band.Columns)
        {
            // Get the width of the column. I added 2 here to account for borders. This doesn't seem
            // exactly right and I think there might be something else causing a slight shift here
            // but it's close enough.                 
            int cellWidth = column.CellSizeResolved.Width + 2;

            bool columnFitsOnCurrentLogicalRow = (totalUsedWidth + cellWidth) <= availableWidth;
            if (columnFitsOnCurrentLogicalRow)
            {
                // Position this column in the current row.                     
                column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.OriginX = x;
                column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.OriginY = y;     

                // Increment x to the next position.                
                x++;                    
            }
            else
            {
                // Reset x and y to the beginning of the next row. 
                x = 0;
                y++;

                // Position the column at the beginning of the next row. 
                column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.OriginX = x;
                column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.OriginY = y;

                // Increment x to the next position.
                x++;

                // Reset TotalUsedWidth since we are starting a new row. 
                totalUsedWidth = 0;
            }

            // The current column either got added to an existing row or a new row. 
            // Either way, we need to increase the total used width. 
            totalUsedWidth += cellWidth;

            // For reasons I won't go into here, the default Span is 2. Set it to 1 to 
            // make things simpler. 
            column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.SpanX = 1;
            column.RowLayoutColumnInfo.SpanY = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you Mike! still having some issue with full screen display and headers but I'll figure that out I guess. your solution works for complex multi-band grids as well by the way :)